# Excluding values from the inrange() function

Tags: stata

I want to know how I could exclude a number from `inrange()`.

For example, if I have a variable `A`:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

I would like to exclude `5` from `inrange(A,2,8)` to produce the following:

```
2,3,4,7,8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also combine `inlist()` and `inrange()`:

```
clear
set obs 10

generate A = _n
generate B = A if inrange(A, 2, 8)
generate C = A if inrange(A, 2, 8) & !inlist(A, 2, 5)

list

     +------------+
     |  A   B   C |
     |------------|
  1. |  1   .   . |
  2. |  2   2   . |
  3. |  3   3   3 |
  4. |  4   4   4 |
  5. |  5   5   . |
     |------------|
  6. |  6   6   6 |
  7. |  7   7   7 |
  8. |  8   8   8 |
  9. |  9   .   . |
 10. | 10   .   . |
     +------------+
```

This will be useful if you want to exclude more than one value.

Answer (score 1):

`inrange()` is a function, not a command. There is no hidden syntax to specify exceptions. If you want between  2 and 8 but not 5, there are many ways to do that, such as

```
if inrange(A, 2, 4) | inrange(A, 6, 8) 

if inrange(A, 2, 8) & A != 5 

if inlist(A, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8)
```

The syntax above doesn't purport to show complete commands. I am taking it as tacit in the question that values are always integer.